# How to give to a Flutter container the Height equivalent to the listview child inside himself

Tags: flutter, user-interface, widget

i have a error when i don't give to the container a height, it's give me this error :

> ======== Exception caught by rendering library ===================================================== The following _CastError was thrown during paint(): Null check operator used on a null value

so that why i gihe hime height :200 but its static height me i want to give to the container a size of listview inside him.

container code :

```
    Container(
       // height:200,
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
          // top: BorderSide(color: Colors.black12),
          bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black12),
        )),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 0, 20),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(width: 22, color: colors),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                  itemCount: reposReplay?.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                          title: Column(children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 10),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Text("${reposReplay?[index].by}",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 14,
                                            color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Text(time,
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 14,
                                            color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]),
                          subtitle: Text("${reposReplay?[index].text!.replaceAll("&#x27;", "'").replaceAll("&gt;", ">").replaceAll("&quot;", "\"").replaceAll("&#x2F;", "/").replaceAll("<p>", "\n").replaceAll("&gt;.&quot;", ">.").replaceAll(exp, "")}",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, color: Colors.black)),
                        ),
                        const Divider(
                          height: 2.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }),
            )
          ],
        )
    ),
```

Comment: if you have one Expanded widget in a Column or Row, all the children need to be wrap with Expanded

Comment: Can you include an image, what  went wrong, and what are you trying to archive?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following inside listview.builder:

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
shrinkWrap: true,
```